# How to get a div that fills the entire screen based on Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap  to wrap my code into using ruby on rails. Now within this parent class, I'd like to add a div (see blue div example on screenshot) that fills entire screen. But it doesn't work, as it keeps the padding of the container div. What to do? The relevant cod is:

In application.html.erb I have

```
<div class="container">
<%= yield %>
</div>
```

In my view file I have

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 blue">Lorem
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css in the view  as:-

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {#add blue class css here}
</style
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">Lorem
  </div>
</div>
```

If the css do not work after adding in this way, then add `!important` with the css.

Eg:-

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {background-color: red !important;}
</style
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">Lorem
  </div>
</div>
```